# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError only when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm getting an uninitialized constant error when my Rails app loads on Heroku, but it works just fine in development.

Heroku Logs (breaks on boot):

```sh
/app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError (NameError)
```

Relevant lines in `controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # ...
  # Line 19
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError, with: :not_processable
  # ...
end
```

If I comment out the `rescue_from`, then I get Internal Server Errors from the uncaught exception if a record fails to save due to restrict_with_error dependencies. If I do rescue from it, then the server fails to boot, but only on production.

I'm guessing this is related to eager load and/or the changes with how zeitwerk loads constants, but I haven't been able to find anything with an answer on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar sounding issue / solution from 2008:

https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/rescue-from-issue-with-aws-uninitialized-constant/28759/2

Their solution was to wrap the constant in a string to avoid file parse time issues with loading, which appears to work for this scenario as well:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # ...
  rescue_from "ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError", with: :not_processable
  # ...
end
```

This issue was reproduced with a minimal app, and an issue opened on Github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43666